# Changing sim cards on iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, sim

I have changed my network provider and inserted their sim into my iPhone 5s. The phone is unlocked, all my contacts were saved...  but the sim card has the default code 0000, and I want to change that - but can't find how to do it.  I have been to Settings - Phone -  but where I expected to see Sim Card on the list - it just wasn't there.  How do I change the sim card code now?

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Mobile Data > Sim PIN

There's a Change PIN option there.
I can't provide a picture as I've never used a SIM PIN, so the screen looks fairly uninteresting ;)

Comment: Found it!!  Never thought of going to Mobile Data.  So, Thanks !

Comment: Welcome - please consider marking this as the accepted answer using the 'tick' ✓ to the left of my answer. [It may not appear immediately for a new user, you may need to come back later] I don't need the points, but it helps future Googlers.